# How to incorporate Rails Engine ApplicationController methods in a main app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I incorporate a Rails engine ApplicationController (it's methods) into a main app? I need to access these engine controller methods, and I'd like to do it without using an 'Include' in my main app's ApplicationController.

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    initializer  "myengine.load_helpers" do
      ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
        include MyEngine::Helpers
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The above was posted on [A way to add before_filter from engine to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323327/a-way-to-add-before-filter-from-engine-to-application/), but my understanding was that helpers are only view-usable, while I need need to access them in my controllers.

Answer (score 7):

I did this before for a rails gem called dynamic_menu

basically it looks like

```
require 'dynamic_menu'

module DynamicMenu
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    initializer "dynamic_menu.menu_items" do |app|
      ActionController::Base.send :include, DynamicMenu::MenuItems
    end
  end
end
```

So I would assume the one you would want would be

```
require 'myEngine'
class Engine < Rails::Engine
  initializer "myengine.load_helpers" do |app|
    ActionController::Base.send :include, MyEngine::Helpers
  end
end
```

You want to add the require of the .rb file you are using found in lib, then it just involves sending the module to the ActionController::Base

See my gem on [github](https://github.com/plowdawg/dynamic_menu) it is pretty simple in nature and may be able to give some guidance.  Comment and I can explain it more.

Comment: Ooops, meant to say 'without', not 'with using an "Include"'. Edited  my post with the fix. So I definitely want an engine and want it seamlessly incorporated into my main app.

Comment: @C Cole that makes quite a bit more sense.    I will update the answer