# How to access Rails Engines methods from main application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, spree, rails-engines

I'm trying to use the current_order method defined in the Spree::Core engine:
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/current_order.rb

In my view, I've tried

```
Spree::Core::CurrentOrder.current_order
```

Using just "current_order" in development works fine though, but not in production.

So then I've tried to require it in my views file like this:

```
require 'spree/core/current_order'
```

I've also tried permutations of these other solutions:

[How to incorporate Rails Engine ApplicationController methods in a main app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124447/how-to-incorporate-rails-engine-applicationcontroller-methods-in-a-main-app)

[A way to add before_filter from engine to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323327/a-way-to-add-before-filter-from-engine-to-application/)

[Rails 3.1: Better way to expose an engine's helper within the client app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797690/rails-3-1-better-way-to-expose-an-engines-helper-within-the-client-app)

But I've lost track of what I actually did.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Maybe I implemented the solutions in the above links incorrectly?

This is the error I'm getting in production:

2012-06-21T09:59:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `current_order' for Spree::Core::CurrentOrder:Module):

If I comment out the lines of code with current_order, everything works in production.

I'm thinking it's the way things are loaded in production?  But this is the first time I'm trying to deploy so I don't quite understand the differences between development and production.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit old, but here is a possible answer, for the record.

Maybe you can work around by using a piece of the spree code in your controller. It's generally a better idea to have the code in the controller (or, in the case of Spree, in a [controller_decorator](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/logic_customization.html)), than in the view.

For example if you need this in your products view as @current_order:

```
Spree::ProductsController.class_eval do
  @current_order = Spree::Order.find(session[:order_id])
end
```

But I don't know why it's working in development and not in production.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I did ended up duplicating the code inside a helper.