# How can I get an engines application controller methods to be available in the main application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am writing an authentication engine that has an authenticate! method in its application controller along with a current user helper method etc.

I would like to be able to call this authenticate! method inside my main application and have it use the current_user that is set by the engines application controller.

After doing a little bit of googling, I ran across this post [How to access Rails Engines methods from main application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135876/how-to-access-rails-engines-methods-from-main-application) but that wasn't helpful and neither were any of the suggested links within.

Right now inside my engine.rb file I have the following code:

```
require 'my_engine'

module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
    initializer "my_engine.load_helpers" do
      ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
        include MyEngine::Helpers
     end
   end
 end
```

end

But this gives me the following error

```
uninitialized constant MyEngine::Helpers
```

What would be the best way to go about getting this done if it is possible?

Before starting this, the way I had things done was to set a session[:current_user_id] which I then passed to a current_user method in the main controller which also housed the authenticate! method that sent the user to the authentication engine. It would be nice if I can just call authenticate! in the main application and have the engines application controller handle that method and set the current user.

Comment: I just happened to find something on http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html . Now I get undefined method `authenticate!'. This would only make it so that I could use the helpers but I think that may work for what I would like to do.

Comment: So it looks like since the helper is just a module I can use include MyEngine::ApplicationHelper and that allows me to at least use authenticate method the way that I want to but I can't seem to figure out how to set the current_user.

Comment: OK, so its available in my controller but not in my view. If I call current_user in a controller method it returns the expected result but inside of a view it returns undefined local variable.

Comment: I needed to put helper_method: current_user in my main applications controller. I was hoping I could put this in the engines application helper but I guess not. I have no idea if I did any of this correctly so definitely looking for critiques on the right way to do this.